# Laravel 5.4: how to use mailbox username instead of email address for sending emails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, smtp, mailboxer

I want to sent emails to clients from my Laravel project. Following are my mail configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.easyname.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=services@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I could not sent emails with these settings and used to get the following error:

```
stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
```

I then contacted my web hosting provided. They suggested me to use the mailbox username for the email id services@mydomain.com. The mailbox username is 112627mail2. I then wrote the username 112627mail2 instead of the email address. This time I got the following error:

```
Swift_RfcComplianceException in MailboxHeader.php line 345:

Address in mailbox given [112627mail2] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

I tried but could not find an answer on how to use a username instead of the email address in mail configuration. Please help.

Comment: I think you can clear the cache

Comment: I did. but it didn't work.

Comment: What is from address in config/mail.php ?

Comment: The from address in mail.php is services@mydomain.com, but the web hosting told me to use mailbox username '112627mail2' instead of the email address. I tried but I get an error.

Comment: Use services@mydomain.com mail address as from address in config/mail.php after clear the cache and try it

Comment: and what about .env file? what should I write there?

Comment: In .env you should set 112627mail2 as MAIL_USERNAME and password as MAIL_PASSWORD

Comment: Thanks. It works now. but I am getting emails in spam and junk folders :(